# How to call a FileReference.browse() from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, flash, externalinterface, filereference

I am trying to call the browse() method of the FileReference class from JavaScript (a user clicks on a text that uses the ExternalInterface to call a method in Flash).

Unfortunately, I receive an error that tells me it has to be a direct action of the user (like clicking a button). I have searched through Google and realized this is a new security feature in Flash 10.

The only solutions I could find was to put a Flash button or to have a hidden flash button over the text, that will call the browse() method.

I wanted the browser only to show JavaScript and all the Flash code only called from JavaScript.

Is there please any way I could please do that?

Thank you very much,
Rudy

Comment: That's the only way to show a Flash file dialog. You can however do stuff like that with HTML 5, without Flash. Google it :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The only solutions I could find was to put a Flash button or to have a hidden flash button over the text, that will call the browse() method.

Those *are* the only solutions.